# TFS Build: Unit Tests fails due to config file location

Tags: tfs, build, automated-tests, configuration-files

I have unit tests setup inside my solution and all works fine locally. However when I run my TFSBuild the unit test fails because the path to a config file is incorrect and I receive a null reference exception.

C:\Builds\1\Apps\Test Solution\tst\Deploy_Server$ 2014-08-07 04_42_38\Out\Resources\TestSettings.config". ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have a config file in my Unit Test project and that is identified (this was a previous issue I fixed this morning) and used. The config file not found above is in a separate project inside the solution and unfortunately the path including the string 'Resources' is hard coded.

My ideal solution would be to configure the build to generate a subfolder under the build path named 'Resources' and then have this config file copied under this sub-directory during the build process.

At this stage I do not want to change anything outside the Test project due to testing implications.

Any thoughts/advice would be much appreciated ?

P.S. Running TFS 2013 on a solution built in VS2010 and the solution built fine before I added in the Unit Tests.

Comment: If you're looking to do pure unit testing, then the config file represents an external dependency that should be mocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just create the folder and copy the config file on build you can do so by adding specific [MSBuild tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) or by using the [pre/post build steps in your projects properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx).

Another option is to configure that you need specific files for your unit test. You do so by adding the following attribute to your test:

```
 [DeploymentItem("source", "targetFolder")]
```

See [How to: Deploy Files for Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms182475(v=vs.120).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi, Ive just tried that by applying the setting [DeploymentItem(@"Resources\TestSettings.config")]. It worked in that the config file was copied to the root of the out directory but I need it to be inside the sub-directory - Resources

Comment: The second argument is a target folder. If you set that to resources it should work.

Comment: Yes changed it to this and it worked: [DeploymentItem(@"Resources\TestSettings.config", "Resources")] Thanks